# Making a dynamic website using core HTML/CSS and PHP or Wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, web

I have to make a **dynamic site** for my assignment, the site **must have an admin panel** where the owner of the site can **change certain visual elements** that will be specified by them.

Now the question is will I have to use core PHP HTML/CSS to do this entirely?
Will Wordpress provide any help in this situation?
I have read people making sites using Wordpress so will this help me regarding my situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WordPress is a CMS.  You'll have a lot of control over the content, and can add additional control by use of Custom Post Types (CPT) and taxonomies.

There are lots of themes you can use and extend by use of [child themes](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes), or you could either build your own from scratch or use a starter theme (I would recommend [Underscores](http://underscores.me/)).

You can, of course, roll your own using HTML, CSS, JavaScript and PHP, but it is a lot more work.

Comment: hi @mikemike, can you please guide me how to built dynamic feature  like user login feature with wordpress.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, definitely WordPress is what you need. There are other solutions like Joomla, Drupal also available but I would suggest to use WordPress though. Using it wou may create your own widgets and specify areas which you want to allow administrator to edit. So basically if WordPress theme is done right the end result will be very good using WordPress.

Answer (score 1):

WordPress is a simple and user-friendly solution for your issue but if you want to avanced custom the admin panel for each user or each group user you must use Drupal : https://www.drupal.org